# Form token, header.php halts the process

Tags: php, csrf

All my webpage includes header.php and footer.php. The header.php has normal stuff like the logo, menu and a search box. I have this code in my header.php to generate tokens for form submission against CSRF.

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnection.php'
    session_start();

    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
```

The generated token is used with the search form which is in my header.php. Once submitted the form is directed to search.php for both token verification and data processing. The search.php too includes the header.php. So every time the search.php is called a new token is generated and the old one cancels out which in turn halts the whole search process. How do I verify the token generated when there is this code in my header.php.

Comment: WHat do you do with the token besides putting it in the session? Also I'm having a hard time connecting all the dots. When / how / why is some search process halted?

Comment: @PeeHaa, I added the token to prevent duplicate record insert on manual page refresh. My search form stores the search term in a database. I do not want a duplicate entry to my database when the user refresh the page manually. Tokens as I have read helps in scaling down CSRF attacks.

Comment: What you did here is called [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). CSRF tokens are to prevent CSRF attacks and are not meant to solve your problem. The solution for your specific problem is called the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You comment above is talking about two entirely different things.

Comment: @PeeHaa, you might consider going through http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html as well. Yes, in my last comment I did point it helps in scaling down CSRF attacks.

Comment: Also I am still not sure what the actual question is :P

Comment: @PeeHaa, he he, never mind, it took me 15 minutes to figure out how to ask.

Comment: Finally @manish if a tutorial is from a domain called `phpro*` and it uses tokens to solve the "user refreshes pages and now I have a double submit" problem you can be sure the tutorial is bad.

Comment: @PeeHaa, you sure, it does the trick though.

Comment: I'm sure. CSRF tokens are to prevent CSRF attacks. Trying to prevent extra submits on refresh using tokens does kinda work, but is the completely wrong tool for the job. Users will still get the annoying *are you sure you want to post the data again* message (or whatever the message is). This problem has already been solved in a "decent" way. Post-Redirect-Get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61605/discussion-between-manish-b-and-peehaa).

Answer (score 0):

You might use another variable to store the last before you overwrite?

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php'
session_start();

$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
if ( isset( $_SESSION['token'] ) ) $_SESSION['last_token'] = $_SESSION['token'];
if ( isset( $_SESSION['token_time'] ) ) $_SESSION['last_token_time'] = $_SESSION['token_time'];

$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
$_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
```

And then later...

```
if ( $_REQUEST['my_token'] == $_SESSION['last_token'] ) {
    // passed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Let me try. If it works, Ill accept your answer. Thanks again Sir.

Comment: I was rather wandering, If I could use the If else statement to check if the token has already been set or not, If it is then proceed with the token value if not then set it. What do you think, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

First of all ... you have semicolon missing after "include 'dbconnection.php'" at line 1. 
Why not just do it this way ?

```
include 'dbconnection.php';
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION['token']) || !isset($_SESSION['token_time'])){
    $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
}else{
    //... do something different
}

$token_age = time() - $_SESSION['token_time'];
if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'] && $token_age <= 300){
    /* Valid Token if same and generated not longer than 5 min ago...*/

}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Semi colon missing is a typing mistake sir and token generation wasn't a problem.

Comment: Go and read this article. http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries Hope it will help